# My app is slow, how to read this Xcode instrument

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

Users are complaining that my app is slow sometimes, so I did allocations profile, check attached image below, Live bytes is around 35 MB.
Is 35 MB fine or I have to lower it?
What's the best Live bytes?

I see ImageIO_PNG_Data & JS garbage collector have the biggest allocation.
How can I clear them?
Thanks

P.S. I'm using ARC

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place. To determine why your application is *slow*, you will need to use one of the CPU instruments (e.g, Time Profiler), not memory allocation.